# Implement Circular progress bar using Recharts

Tags: css, reactjs, charts, pie-chart, recharts

I'm using [recharts](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/PieChartWithPaddingAngle) library for PieCharts.

With `paddingAngle={0}` able to remove padding angle but want to remove cell separator(white color).

Code:

```html
const data = [
            { id: "1", name: "L1", value: 75 },
            { id: "2", name: "L2", value: 25 }
            ];

<PieChart width={50} height={50}>
  <text
    x={25}
    y={25}
    textAnchor="middle"
    dominantBaseline="middle"
  >
    25
  </text>
  <Pie
    data={data}
    dataKey="value"
    innerRadius="80%"
    outerRadius="100%"
    fill="#82ca9d"
    startAngle={90}
    endAngle={-270}
    paddingAngle={0}
    cornerRadius={5}
  >
    <Cell
      key="test"
      fill="#CCC"
    />
  </Pie>
</PieChart>
```

Current Looks like:

[image]

want to implement like this:

[image]

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please share some code with us so we can properly understand your problem and help you.

Comment: @CodeMeNatalie Please see updated question with code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally got the solution.  Instead of doing the workaround with `PieChart`, would suggest using `RadialBarChart`

Solution:

```
const data = [
  { name: 'L1', value: 25 }
];

const circleSize = 30;

<RadialBarChart
  width={circleSize}
  height={circleSize}
  cx={circleSize / 2}
  cy={circleSize / 2}
  innerRadius={12}
  outerRadius={18}
  barSize={2}
  data={data}
  startAngle={90}
  endAngle={-270}
  >
  <PolarAngleAxis
  type="number"
  domain={[0, 100]}
  angleAxisId={0}
  tick={false}
  />
  <RadialBar
  background
  clockWise
  dataKey="value"
  cornerRadius={circleSize / 2}
  fill="#82ca9d"
  />
  <text
  x={circleSize / 2}
  y={circleSize / 2}
  textAnchor="middle"
  dominantBaseline="middle"
  className="progress-label"
  >
  25
  </text>
</RadialBarChart>
```

Comment: But it will fill the entire circle, won't it?

Answer (score 2):

From `v.1.2.0` property `blendStroke` has been added to `PieChart`. So what you need to do is add it to your Pie component. I hope this will help you!

```html
const data = [
  { id: "1", name: "L1", value: 75 },
  { id: "2", name: "L2", value: 25 }
];

<PieChart width={50} height={50}>
  <text
    x={25}
    y={25}
    textAnchor="middle"
    dominantBaseline="middle"
  >
    25
  </text>
  <Pie
    data={data}
    dataKey="value"
    innerRadius="80%"
    outerRadius="100%"
    fill="#82ca9d"
    startAngle={90}
    endAngle={-270}
    paddingAngle={0}
    blendStroke
  >
    <Cell
      key="test"
      fill="#CCC"
    />
  </Pie>
</PieChart>
```

Comment: @HarshalWani Simply remove `cornerRadius` from Pie component.

Comment: please avoid convertiong code to snippet automatically like you have done here : https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21726823 .. the edit was completely irrelevant. You simply clicked on the *tiny* button removing the whitespaces that are the core of the question

Comment: @CodeMeNatalie Got a correct solution (y)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53847014/2226399